# Что такое последовательный обход дерева?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, дерево

Задали реализовать последовательный обход дерева, но я так и не смог ничего найти о нем в инете. Если вы знакомы с ним или хотя бы догадываетесь, что это такое, буду благодарен за объяснение или линки.

Comment: У Кнута в "Искусстве программирования" вроде было... Ну а гугл сказал в числе прочего: http://www.tvd-home.ru/recursion#p5_2

Answer (score 2):

Подобный термин вижу впервые.

Мне кажется, что такими словами могут называть рекурсивный обход в глубину, когда сначала посещается левое (для бинарного дерева, а если дерево n-арное, то самое первое поддерево в списке поддеревьев данного узла) поддерево, затем берется значение узла, а затем правое поддерево.

Конечно это зависит от организации (природы) дерева. Например, в случае иерерхической файловой системы мы видим  дерево каталогов с переменной арностью узлов и каждый узел может содержать несколько (в том чисе ноль) элементов данных (файлов).

С другой стороны, можно представить последовательный список значений и бинарное дерево поиска, листья которого ссылаются на элементы этого списка. Тогда результатом обхода будут только листья, хотя порядок обхода сохранится (как описано выше).

Answer (score 2):

Последовательный обход дерева, это алгоритм обхода дерева, при котором обходятся все ветки дерева и каждая ветка обходится 1 раз. Есть математическая теорема которая доказывает, что такой алгоритм возможен, вне зависимости от количества веток (главное чтобы ветки не образовывали кольца - впрочем если ветки образовывают кольца - то это уже не дерево).

Простейшая реализация обхода дерева это рекурсивный алгоритм, поскольку любая часть дерева является деревом. Рекурсия продолжается до тех пор пока поддерево не выродится в ветку.

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется что наоборот, [обход в ширину](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83).
Ну а вообще такие вещи, если не ясно, нужно сразу уточнять у препода, не стесняться спросить.